# Differences in padding alignments in Firefox vs others

Tags: html, css, user-interface, alignment

Please check the below fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/a13nd32u/3/

```
 #post_part{display:inline;padding:6px 9px;float:right;font-size:15px}
 select{width:80px;height:21px;padding-right:10px;display:inline} 
 #button1{display:inline;padding-left:10px}
 #post_button{height:24px;width:70px;font-size:14px;-webkit-appearance:     none;}
```

the post button is getting outside the box however in other browsers Its appearing perfectly fine. Can someone please help

Comment: Browsers render buttons / UI elements differently, I'd recommend adding your own styles (like `border:1px solid #000`) and others to make sure the buttons are the same cross-platforms. Also try using CSS resets

Answer (score 1):

To be certain to have a correct appearance between browsers, you should try to use a reset.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Still not helping :( .

Comment: Cool! don't forget to accept the answer :p
Happy styling!